# How to set MaxReceivedMessageSize for Owin/Katana

Tags: f#, owin, katana

Pretty straight forward question.

The default size limit of `MaxReceivedMessageSize` (64kb) is to small for what I'm trying to do.

There's a ton of examples for how to do this in C# but I can't seem to find an example of how to do it in F#

Has anyone gotten this to work?

[The MSDN Documentation isn't very helpful](https://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/system.servicemodel.httpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you have a problem?

Comment: lol I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to set. I've explored the different libraries available in System.ServiceModel and I don't see anything in there. I've also tried to get BasicHttpBinding to work but this doesn't have any affect either. @FyodorSoikin

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing that all those C# examples tell you to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but what is wrong with `HttpBindingBase.MaxReceivedMessageSize  <- 128000`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I have tried, I'm not really that savy with F# yet so I'm having trouble converting over. Which is why I'm looking for an example of it already implemented

Comment: @s952163 It says that HttpBindingBase.MaxReceivedMessageSize isn't static

Comment: @AnthonyRussell so create an instance first of whatever class this belongs to (I assume `HttpBindingBase`), then set the property to the value on that instance. Can you show the C# code at least?

Comment: @s952163 I created the instance after your last comment but I don't know what to do with it now that it's set lol. I imagine you need to give it back to something so it can use it.

Comment: It will help if you show your code, specifically the binding you are trying to use to create an endpoint/connection.  Some bindings will expose this property knob directly, whereas others might not and you may need to use a custom binding.

Comment: You have tagged this with owin and katana, however HttpBindingBase and MaxReceivedMessageSize are relating to WCF